# Making a PUT route, targeting a specific turtle (Node, express)

Tags: node.js

So the instructions say:

- Make a PUT route
- will target a specific turtle
- This will use params in the route.
- You are not expected to target an object
- return "LOOK OUT (targeted turtle) IS MUTATING!!!"
- use CURL

This is what I have so far (I'm probably totally wrong but I gave it a try)

```
app.put('/turtles/:id', function(req, res) {
var turtle = req.params.id
data = { 
    Raphael: "Red",
    Leonardo: "Blue",
    Donatello: "Black",
    Michaelangelo: "Orange"
} 

console.log("LOOK OUT " + req.params.id + " IS MUTATING!!!")
```

What is the problem? Am I on the right track?

Comment: didn't get the question, can u please put some more light on requirement?

Comment: Can you provide an example request / `curl` command? What is the output that you see? What output did you expect, if different? "*Am I on the right track?*" Possibly. How is `data` supposed to be used? Is the message expected in the response back to `curl` or in the server's own console (these aren't the same)?

Comment: In order to get a good answer here **you** will need to answer the question: "What is the problem?" What is happening that is incorrect? What did you expect to happen? Where did the error occur? Answers will begin to be possible after these types of clarifying questions have been answered in your question. In it's current state, it's very difficult to answer this question, because it's unclear what you're asking.